# When libcurl initiates an https request, the client hello does not carry the session ticket field

Tags: curl, https, openssl

```
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main()
{
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    CURLSH *sh = curl_share_init();
    curl_share_setopt(sh, CURLSHOPT_SHARE, CURL_LOCK_DATA_SSL_SESSION);
    CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SHARE, sh);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://xxx");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    
    auto ret = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    
    curl_share_cleanup(sh);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    curl_global_cleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

I tried `openssl s_client -connect xxx:443` , the client hello in this way will carry the session ticket field and the ticket can be used normally. But curl https://xxx will not carry the session ticket field.

So anyone knows what the problem is?

Comment: Which stack/library does your build of libcurl use? If you don't know, (commandline) `curl -V` (upper vee) should show it.

Comment: curl 7.58.0-DEV (aarch64-apple-darwin20.5.0) libcurl/7.58.0-DEV OpenSSL/1.1.1k zlib/1.2.11
Release-Date: [unreleased]
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP UnixSockets HTTPS-proxy

Answer (score 2):

Okay, it seems curl using OpenSSL disables tickets [in lib/vtls/openssl.c](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/master/lib/vtls/openssl.c#L2722). The preceding comment block suggests this was added by a patch for some reason, but I didn't go through the commit history to find out what; it does assert you can change it using the SSL callback.

Note OpenSSL 1.1.1 supports TLS1.3 which unless you disable it will be used whenever the server agrees. TLS1.3 no longer uses old-style (RFC4507/5077) tickets, and no longer does old-style session resumption at all, either with session-id or ticket. Instead it has a new forward-secret scheme using a temporary derived PSK; this uses the *message type* 'NewSessionTicket' that was formerly used for tickets, but it no longer contains a ticket, and it is no longer dependent on the 'ticket' extension in hello. See RFC8446 for details.

Comment: Right! Everything is ok when using `SSL_CTX_clear_options(ctx, SSL_OP_NO_TICKEY)`. But I can hardly find out why curl has this change and why it has to be changed like this.Thx！